# 日本語を含む行のTAB（インデント）がずれる件について

Tags: atom-editor

お世話になっております。

Atomで、以下のような日本語（全角文字）を含む行に対して
TABキーでインデントを揃えようとすると、きれいに揃わずズレてしまいます。

```
SELECT
    氏名        AS  NAME
,   生年月日    AS  BIRTHDAY
,   スキル      AS  SKILL
FROM
    ...
```

同じコードを、サクラエディタやVSCodeに貼り付けると
`AS`の列できれいにインデントが揃います。

サクラエディタ
[image: sakura]

VSCode
[image: vscode]

Atom（ズレる）
[image: atom]

サクラ、VSCode、Atomともに、
フォントは「ＭＳ ゴシック」と「Ricty Diminished」で、
タブは「幅4のハードタブ」で確認しております。

なお、半角文字のみの場合はこのようなズレは起こらないようです。

Atom（ズレない）
[image: atom_hankaku]

このズレは、Atomの設定で解決可能でしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

環境:

- Windows 10
- Atom 1.27.2

Comment: こちらの環境 (Atom 1.27.2 (Tab Type: hard), Electron 1.7.15, Chrome 58.0.3029.110, Node 7.9.0, Ubuntu 18.04) でも再現しました。Atom の [issue トラッカー](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues)に報告して良いもののように思います。類似の issue として ["Atom doesn't correctly indent lines with combining diacritics"](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/15090) がありますが、より広い範囲のバグのようです。

Comment: VS Codeは今年に入ってからの修正です。

Comment: (また、コメント入力に失敗) VS Codeは今年に入ってからの修正です。それ以前は同様でした。(過去に同様の質問あり、、、リンクはどうやるか不明なので検索を) Atomからの派生と聞くので、原因は同じじゃないかと思うのですが、ソースを見ていませんので、不明。 なお、VS Codeも修正済みと思われたのですが、別の記号(例えば、≪)とかではNG (結果は違うが) という事で、参考情報。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。Atom の issue トラッカー...すみません、GitHub の使い方が分からない状態ですので、調べつつ、ご教示いただきました類似の issue の様子を見たいと思います。